# Magnitude of off-diagonal terms in density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

I want to prove that if I have a density matrix of the form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{++}& p_{+-}\\
p_{-+}&p_{--}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then $|p_{+-}|^2 = |p_{-+}|^2 \le p_{++}p_{--}$. (This was stated [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/density-matrix-off-diagonal-elements.660288/)). However, I don't know where to start. I appreciate if you could point the way to prove this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since density matrix is hermitian, $p_{+-}=p_{-+}^*$.  As the eigenvalues are necessarily non-negative:
$$
\hbox{Det}\begin{pmatrix}
p_{++}& p_{+-}\\
p_{-+}&p_{--}
\end{pmatrix}= p_{++}p_{--}-\vert p_{+-}\vert^2 \ge 0
$$
and the result follows.